# Texture paint paints some pattern

Tags: mesh, texture-painting

Heres the model with UV map, i unpacked it again and created a new inage for it, so UV would me clean, but no result. U can see the red markings on UV from my brush.[image: [1]]I was trying to paint on my model, and this happened for some reason. I didnt want to paint like this, i was painting with the casual brush. Looks like the pattern is the actual UV map.[image]. [image: The problem]*Its dull from inside

Comment: Have you tried removing doubles in edit mode? That kind of pattern can often be cause by having lots of duplicate geometry.

Comment: Tried it now - removed 0 vertices

Comment: Interesting... Can you add a screenshot of the object in edit mode with the UV map?

Comment: It looks like you are using the texture you are trying to paint as the brush texture. Have you set up a material with the texture you are trying to paint? Are you trying to use a textured brush or a default brush?

Comment: Im trying to use a normal brush I dont know that i set texture as the brush. how can I reverse it?

Comment: Check out the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that the pattern looks like an UV unwrap painted image, so look to see if you have also loaded your unwrapped texture as your texture brush - because if you do, you will see this pattern continue to tile across your painted object. Simple method is to look under your brush for the Texture panel and press the X to disconnect any texture from the brush.